# Python long string to justified text of x characters long lines

Tags: python, regex

As an assignment I have to take in a long string of text then output it justified with each line being x characters long.
The current method I am trying to use is not working and I can not figure out why, it just gets stuck in an infinite loop.

I would appreciate some help with debugging my code.

code:

```
words = 'Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.'.split()
max_len = 60
line = ''
lines = []
for word in words:
    if len(line) + len(word) <= max_len:
        line += (' ' + word)
    else:
        lines.append(line.strip())
        line = ''

import re
def JustifyLine(oline, maxLen):
    if len(oline) < maxLen:
        s = 1
        nline = oline
        while len(nline) < maxLen:
            match = '\w(\s{%i})\w' % s
            replacement = ' ' * (s + 1)
            nline = re.sub(match, replacement, nline, 1)
            if len(re.findall(match, nline)) == 0:
                s = s + 1
                replacement = s + 1
            elif len(nline) == maxLen:
                return nline
    return oline

for l in lines[:-1]:
    string = JustifyLine(l, max_len)
    print(string)
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Why not try debugging yourself by inserting some prints every now and then? :-)

Comment: the long string at the top needs to be outputted to justified text with a max line length of 60 characters as show here on the left: http://cdn.designinstruct.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/image_03_espen_brunborg.jpg

Comment: I have tried debugging for over 2 hours now and can't find my problem

Comment: If the lines must be 60 character long, then the line break will be inserted in most places in the middle of the word, not on the white space. Is that ok with you or do you have to have the line breaks on white space only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your major problem is that you are replacing letter-whitespace-letter with more white space, deleting the letters on either side of it.  So your line never gets longer, and your loop never terminates.

Put the letters in their own groups, and add references (e.g., \1) to the replacement string.

Comment: This seems to get me a bit further thanks, but it seems it is also replacing the third group now with: `replacement = '\g<1>' + (' ' * (s + 1))`

Comment: You get keep the last group with this:
`replacement = r'\g<1>' + ' ' * (s + 1) + r'\g<2>'`
Note that there is no reason to put the replaced white space itself into a group, hence this snippet expects only two groups in the pattern.

Comment: Leading question: does your program output _all_ the words of the input text?

Answer (score 1):

Stephen's answer gives you a bit more than I was going to give you.

Suggestions for the future:

1. Work out what loop isn't terminating. e.g. add print statements to suspect loops. A different character to each.
2. Print out the key values for the loop condition and check that they are heading the right way. In this case the length of nline. If it isn't increasing every time through you need to worry that it won't terminate.
3. Think carefully before having two loop exits (the condition on the loop and the the return), it can make it harder to reason about the behaviour.